# CakePHP SecurityComponent is blackholing my ReCAPTCHA

Tags: php, cakephp, captcha

I'm using [Jahdrien's ReCAPTCHA plugin](https://github.com/Jahdrien/ReCaptcha-Plugin) in my CakePHP 2.4 app, which installs just fine. The problem is that I'm using SecurityComponent to protect against forged forms, which is also protecting me against the ReCAPTCHA plugin.

I've got the plugin set up on my Users controller and enabled on my `register` action, but when I try to register a user I get an error: *The request has been black-holed.* Cake has detected the extra field from the CAPTCHA and suspects foul play.

The question is: How do I whitelist the CAPTCHA without opening my entire form to attacks? I inspected the element and saw that the input's name is `recaptcha_response_field`, so I tried unlocking it by name right before the CAPTCHA, to no effect.

```
$this->Form->unlockField('recaptcha_response_field');
echo $this->Recaptcha->show(array(
    'theme' => 'white',
    'lang' => 'en',
));
```

Comment: In your beforeFilter() function you can manually add the recaptcha response field to your CSRF if the action is the one that you want it to apply to.

Comment: also you have to add or unlock the `recaptcha_question_field`

Comment: I found a solution of sorts: Use a different ReCAPTCHA plugin. The CakeDC one is unit tested and it registers itself with SecurityComponent so it doesn't need unlocking: https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha